# How to create single JWT authentication and authorisation server for multiple website and mobile apps in ASP.NET Core

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, authorization

I find setting up the auth services for every website is cumbersome.

This is my scenario: I have currently three websites for example `example.com`, `example.org` and `example.space` and their mobile apps respectively.

I found it's tiring to configure auth for each of them separately. What I want is to create a centralise auth service running on a different port with a different database. For example on `example.net:7000`.

Whenever users request to be authenticated by sending their `email` and `password` to `example.com/auth`, `example.org/auth` or maybe just `example.net/auth` they will receive a JWT token which can be used to access the protected resources on the respective sites or their mobile apps. And it should be without opening any website from the browser in case of the mobile apps.

I mean users shouldn't be aware of this process that their credentials is being handling by a single server. It's kind of like Google where user can login on to `gmail.com` and also gets logged in to `google.com`.

I have taken a look to `Openiddict` but found out that it has some redirections involved (to auth a user, the user is being redirected to the auth server and then send back to the previous url). I want it to be like machine to machine communication with no user interactions involved rather than sending an JSON containing their credential in a simple HTTP POST API request.

How can I achieve this? Is there any example repository.

Note: I am using Flutter for the mobile apps.

Comment: you want to use central auth service but you don't want to use central auth server. kind of contradict with in your question it self. and if I understand correctly then you are looking for SingleSignOn feature. search for that and you will get many examples.

Comment: No! I want a single token issuer server for multiple audience.

Comment: check for [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) or [idenityserver](https://duendesoftware.com/products/identityserver)